# Expected to find element: #VTK-j_idt1363, but never found it

Tags: cypress

I am facing an issue on clicking an element. I need an element to be clicked while the network is slow by not using wait() and pause().The page loads after or more than 35sec(350000).Could someone help me to solve the issue,please?

Here is my coding.

```
it('Test ship',function(){

cy.viewport(1120,800)


 cy.visit('url')

 cy.get('#LoginForm-nfr_login_authname').type('username')

 cy.get('#LoginForm-nfr_login_authid').type('paSSw0rd')

 cy.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
     return false
 })
 

 //These two were the elements present in the same page.The Workspace (first command) gets loaded and error occurs before clicking the second element.

  cy.wait[ cy.xpath('//span[normalize-space()="Work Space"]') .click({force: true})]

//here I have used wait 
  
cy.wait(80000)
 cy.get('#VTK-j_idt1262').click({force: true})

})
```

I have tried many possible ways such as alias,etc..,

Please let me know about the solution to wait for page loading without using wait() and pause() command.

[error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXDaE.png)

Comment: Please the add the code where you are using `wait` and `pause` ?

Comment: Can you add the specific error message?

Comment: added@https://stackoverflow.com/users/4571271/alapan-das @https://stackoverflow.com/users/11625850/agoff